# Find the value of $\sin 10^\circ + \sin 20^\circ + \sin 30^\circ - \sin 360^\circ $

Tags: trigonometry

How to solve this manually ?

**EDIT:** In my module the answer is given as **$0$** but when I used mathematica `N[Sin[10 Degree] + Sin[20 Degree] + Sin[30 Degree] - Sin[360 Degree],50]` gives **$1.0156683209925990818958162414 \cdots$** (truncated)

So I guess there is some mistake in the problem statement.

Comment: Start with $\sin(360^\circ) = 0$.

Comment: Mathematica uses radians, not degrees, so what you've computed is not the expression in the title of your question. But it is true that the answer is definitely not zero.

Comment: Sin[x] takes radians by default, doesn't it?  The correct answer has decimal approximation 1.015668320992...

Comment: @ Hans Lundmark :Thanks for the update :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The last two terms have [simple well-known values](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exact_trigonometric_constants).
The first two are less appetizing; see [here for 10 degrees](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi18.html) and [here for 20 degrees](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/TrigonometryAnglesPi9.html).

Answer (score 1):

No, the answer is definitely not zero. But, of course, you have

$$ \sum_{k=0}^{36} \sin(n\times 10°) = 0 $$