# Solve for x $ \sin 30° \sin x \sin 10° = \sin 20° \sin ({80°-x}) \sin 40° $

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

$ \sin 30° \sin x \sin 10° = \sin 20° \sin ({80°-x}) \sin 40° $

I tried transformation formulas , $ 2\sin a \sin b $ one. I know the value of sin 30° but what about others?

Original problem

In triangle ABC, P is an interior point such that $ \angle PAB = 10°. \angle PBA = 20° PAC = 40°  \angle PCA = 30° $ then what kind of triangle it is ?  I solved it till I got stuck here.

Answer (score 1):

Assume AB = 1.

[image]

Apply sine law to PAB to get $PB = 2 \sin 10^0$.

Apply sine law to PAC to get $PB = 2 \sin 20^0$ and $PC = 4 \sin 20^0 \sin 40^0$.

Apply cosine law to PBC to get $BC$ in terms of those angles. Note that $\cos 100^0 = - \sin 10^0$.

$BC^2 = 4 \sin^2 10 + 16 \sin^220^0\sin^2 40^0 + 16 \sin 20^0 \sin 40^0 \sin^210^0$

Suggestion:- Convert all angles in $BC^2$to $\sin 10^0$ (or $\sin 20^0$) by compound angle formula. Hope that the result is 1.

Answer (score -2):

Like [Solve $\frac{\sin(xº)\sin(80º)}{\sin(170º - xº) \sin(70º)} = \frac {\sin(60º)}{\sin (100º)}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3252593/solve-frac-sinx%C2%BA-sin80%C2%BA-sin170%C2%BA-x%C2%BA-sin70%C2%BA-frac-sin60%C2%BA/3252622#3252622)

$$\dfrac{\sin(80-x)}{\sin x}=\dfrac{\sin30\sin10}{\sin20\sin40}$$

$$\implies\sin80\cot x-\cos80=\dfrac{\sin30\sin10}{\sin20\sin40}=\dfrac{4\sin10\sin80}{2\sin(3\cdot20)}$$

using https://brainly.in/question/3475250

$$\implies\cos10\cot x=\sin10\left(1+4\cos10\tan30\right)$$

$$\implies\sqrt3\cot x=\sqrt3\tan10+4\sin10$$

Like [Simplifying $\tan100^{\circ}+4\sin100^{\circ}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1434561/simplifying-tan100-circ4-sin100-circ/1436702#1436702)

set $A=360 n-3x$ in $2\sec A\sin x+\tan x=-\tan A$

$$2\sec3x\sin x+\tan x=\tan3x$$

Here $x=10\implies2\cdot\dfrac2{\sqrt3}\sin10+\tan10=\dfrac1{\sqrt3}\iff4\sin10+\sqrt3\tan10=1$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: $A=360 n-3x$ in $2\sec A\sin x+\tan x=-\tan A$
Can you please explain this? How you got this equation. Is it something one should remember?

Comment: @hyphen, Have you checked the linked post?

Comment: Yes, I have. Lab Bhattacharjee.